# where can i get a tutorial for using visual studio installer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, installation

Anyone have suggestions on good tutorials or examples of how to create MSI packages using visual studio?

In particular, I'm interested in creating a deployment package for an ASP.NET website.

Comment: Do you mean creating installers?

Comment: Checking in his questions and answers you could see it's not that, but the way this question was written it completely misleads you to understand he doesn't know how to instal visual studio itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming by "Visual Studio Installer" you mean creating an installer in Visual Studio, [this one](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=58021) seems like it covers quite a few topics.  It gives you a quick and dirty way (via wizard) to get your installer working, then goes into details on how to change other properties, like version numbers, icons and such.

The wording of your title might prevent people from attempting to answer because Visual Studio Install is taken to mean the installer for putting VS on your system, whereas the wording of your questions and your history on SO indicate that you have VS installed and are probably wanting to create an installer for a VS project.  Clarifying this point will probably give you better responses.