# C# Copying Resources / Making a Installer

Tags: c#, file, io, foreach, resources

I want to make a Installer, that copies the Resources (from Resources.resx) to a specific location.
It works kind of, it copies the Files, but without file extensions.
Here is the code:
    ResourceSet ResSet = Mining.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry file in ResSet)
{
    using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file.Key.ToString()))
    {
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Programme\Special\" + file.Key.ToString() ,
                        ObjectToByteArray(file));
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Programme\Special\target\" + file.Key.ToString(),
                        ObjectToByteArray(file));
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Programme\Special\target\libs\" + file.Key.ToString(),
                        ObjectToByteArray(file));
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Programme\Special\target\libs\natives\" +
                        file.Key.ToString(), 
                    ObjectToByteArray(file));
    Console.WriteLine("Continuing...");

    }
}
```

Plus, I dont know how  to put the correct file into the correct Folder, so i put every file in every folder...

Comment: You really should just use an installer. It's much more flexible and is integrated with Windows that way - possible duplicate of [where can i get a tutorial for using visual studio installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547729/where-can-i-get-a-tutorial-for-using-visual-studio-installer)

Comment: Favourited for interest...

Comment: Just add the file extension on the end? `File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Programme\Special\" + file.Key.ToString() + ".fileExtension`

Comment: @RalfKeller Is it fair to say that you don't want to use OneClick?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Thank you, I think I am going to do this.

Comment: @tnw there are different Extensions...

Comment: @phcoding In fact, I want to see how it works when I do it by myself